# How to prevent a synchronized tremolo bridge from lifting

Tags: electric-guitar, maintenance, bridge, tremolo-system

I recently changed the strings on my Ibanez GIO GRG170DX and I noticed that after tuning the guitar, the bridge was lifting up (no longer flat with the body). I don't think it was like this before restringing, but I can't figure out what to do to fix it.

I watched a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyRUCJa11vY) which recommended that I loosen the screws on the front of the bridge, but when I did that it didn't really seem to help.

How can I prevent my synchronized tremolo bridge from lifting?

[image: Bridge from the side]
[image: Bridge from the bottom]
[image: Bridge from the top]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn the guitar over so the bottom is visible. There should be a plastic panel held on with screws. Undo the screws and take the panel off. Inside, there should be springs that connect the bridge and tremolo to a metal bracket that is like a claw.

The metal bracket should have screws in it also that go through the bracket and into the body of the guitar. Tighten the screws to pull the springs tighter and lower the bridge again.

Be sure to loosen the strings before you tighten the bracket screws to prevent the strings from breaking. You probably have to go back and forth loosening the strings and tightening the screws and then tune the strings up and see if the bridge is where you want.

Replace the plastic panel on the back and screw it back into place.

Comment: I tried this but wasn't able to screw in the screws enough to make a difference, so I ended up bringing it to a shop to get it repaired. It turned out that the guitar was missing a spring and when I changed string gauges the spring tension of just the 2 springs simply wasn't enough.

Comment: @KevinJohnson Ah yes. A lot of guitars come with a third spring not installed for use with thicker strings. I should edit that in. It wasn’t clear from your question that you had changed string gauges.

Answer (score 0):

Changing strings on a floating trem bridge requires never changing gauge, and changing stings fully one by one, not taking them all off. It's pretty limiting if you want to deviate then you will have to go through all these steps:

- blocking the trem
- changing strings one by one
- adjusting trem counter pressure